# When converting a utf-8 encoded string from bytes to characters, how does the computer know where a character ends?

Tags: string, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

Given a Unicode string encoded in UTF-8, which is just bytes in memory.

If a computer wants to convert these bytes to its corresponding Unicode codepoints (numbers), how can it know where one character ends and another one begins? Some characters are represented by 1 byte, others by up to 6 bytes. So if you have

```
00111101 10111001
```

This could represent 2 characters, or 1. How does the computer decide which it is to interpret it correctly? Is there some sort of convention from which we can know from the first byte how many bytes the current character uses or something?

Comment: UTF-8 was restricted to 4 bytes 10 years ago, you are probably using some outdated source. Anyway, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) explains the scheme pretty well.

Comment: It was an old source but that doesn't really change the question :) You have a point though, wikipedia is quite clear

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first byte of a multibyte sequence encodes the length of the sequence in the number of leading 1-bits:

- `0xxxxxxx` is a character on its own;
- `10xxxxxx` is a continuation of a multibyte character;
- `110xxxxx` is the first byte of a 2-byte character;
- `1110xxxx` is the first byte of a 3-byte character;
- `11110xxx` is the first byte of a 4-byte character.

Bytes with more than 4 leading 1-bits don't encode valid characters in UTF-8 because the 4-byte sequences already cover more than the entire Unicode range from U+0000 to U+10FFFF.

So, the example posed in the question has one ASCII character and one continuation byte that doesn't encode a character on its own.