# Implement a function to check if a string/byte array follows utf-8 format

Tags: java, string, utf-8

I am trying to solve this interview question.

> After given clearly definition of UTF-8 format. ex: 1-byte   :
>   0b0xxxxxxx 2- bytes:.... Asked to write a function to validate whether
>   the input is valid UTF-8. Input will be string/byte array, output
>   should be yes/no.

I have two possible approaches.

First, if the input is a string, since UTF-8 is at most 4 byte, after we remove the first two characters "0b", we can use Integer.parseInt(s) to check if the rest of the string is at the range 0 to 10FFFF. Moreover, it is better to check if the length of the string is a multiple of 8 and if the input string contains all 0s and 1s first. So I will have to go through the string twice and the complexity will be O(n).

Second, if the input is a byte array (we can also use this method if the input is a string), we check if each 1-byte element is in the correct range. If the input is a string, first check the length of the string is a multiple of 8 then check each 8-character substring is in the range.

I know there are couple solutions on how to check a string using Java libraries, but my question is how I should implement the function based on the question.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the string actually contain "0" then "b" then 8 "1"s and "0"s, or did the interviewer mean that those are the bits in each byte? (UTF-8 format suggests they mean the latter)

Comment: If it's a Java String, then it does not really have an encoding. Only bytestrems do. Characters are already decoded. Java represents them as UTF-16 internally, so they will always be compatible with UTF-8.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisSavard I would have thought so, but "after we remove the first two characters 0b we can use Integer.parseInt(s)" ...

Comment: Hopefully helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688569/when-converting-a-utf-8-encoded-string-from-bytes-to-characters-how-does-the-co?rq=1

Comment: Yet another stupid interview question. Never had to do this in 18 years of Java for byte arrays, and if the input is a String the question is asinine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I am grateful for the comments and the answer. 
First of all, I have to agree that this is "another stupid interview question". It is true that in Java String is already encoded, so it will always be compatible  with UTF-8. One way to check it is given a string:

```
public static boolean isUTF8(String s){
    try{
        byte[]bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, since all the printable strings are in the unicode form, so I haven't got a chance to get an error.

Second, if given a byte array, it will always be in the range -2^7(0b10000000) to 2^7(0b1111111), so it will always be in a valid UTF-8 range.

My initial understanding to the question was that given a string, say "0b11111111", check if it is a valid UTF-8, I guess I was wrong.

Moreover, Java does provide constructor to convert byte array to string, and if you are interested in the decode method, check [here](http://www.codatlas.com/github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/HEAD/src/share/classes/java/lang/StringCoding.java?line=250).

One more thing, the above answer would be correct given another language. The only improvement could be:

> In November 2003, UTF-8 was restricted by RFC 3629 to end at U+10FFFF, in order to match the constraints of the UTF-16 character encoding. This removed all 5- and 6-byte sequences, and about half of the 4-byte sequences.

So 4 bytes would be enough.

I am definitely to this, so correct me if I am wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The method you've posted should just return false, as UTF-16 isn't the same as UTF-8. It doesn't even make sense to write the method, or to ask for it.

Comment: @EJP what is the string you used as the import? Thanks.

Comment: String in Java is always UTF-16 encoded, so your function should return false all the time

Comment: A boolean function that returns only true or does a System.exit is not good. You should check your semantic and let it return false. BTW the function would never return false because UTF-8 is a valid encoding and Java has just to convert from its internal UTF-16 representation to UTF-8.

Answer (score 16):

Let's first have a look at a [visual representation of the UTF-8 design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

[image]

---

Now let's resume what we have to do.

- Loop over all character of the string (each character being a byte).
- We will need to apply a mask to each byte depending on the codepoint as the `x` characters represent the actual codepoint. We will use the binary AND operator (`&`) which copy a bit to the result if it exists in both operands.
- The goal of applying a mask is to remove the trailing bits so we compare the actual byte as the first code point. We will do the bitwise operation using `0b1xxxxxxx` where 1 will appear "Bytes in sequence" time, and other bits will be 0.
- We can then compare with the first byte to verify if it is valid, and also determinate what is the actual byte.
- If the character entered in none of the case, it means the byte is invalid and we return "No".
- If we can get out of the loop, that means each of the character are valid, hence the string is valid.
- Make sure the comparison that returned true correspond to the expected length.

---

The method would look like this :

```
public static final boolean isUTF8(final byte[] pText) {

    int expectedLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pText.length; i++) {
        if ((pText[i] & 0b10000000) == 0b00000000) {
            expectedLength = 1;
        } else if ((pText[i] & 0b11100000) == 0b11000000) {
            expectedLength = 2;
        } else if ((pText[i] & 0b11110000) == 0b11100000) {
            expectedLength = 3;
        } else if ((pText[i] & 0b11111000) == 0b11110000) {
            expectedLength = 4;
        } else if ((pText[i] & 0b11111100) == 0b11111000) {
            expectedLength = 5;
        } else if ((pText[i] & 0b11111110) == 0b11111100) {
            expectedLength = 6;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        while (--expectedLength > 0) {
            if (++i >= pText.length) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((pText[i] & 0b11000000) != 0b10000000) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

**Edit :** The actual method is not the original one (almost, but not) and is stolen from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59428/validating-utf-8-byte-array). The original one was not properly working as per @EJP comment.

Comment: This answer is handy, but it does not detect some dangerous violations, such as non-minimal UTF-8 sequences. Naively using bytes, considered "valid" by the code in answer may result in security issues and/or data loss. Example: take some non-minimal NUL sequences from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1319229/1643723, feed them to the code. It will consider them valid. Then feed them to insecure consumer (such as `String` constructor in Android 5+). Now decode resulting String back to UTF-8. The bytes will be different now! Four-byte NUL will turn into one-byte NUL…

Comment: … this have some unpleasant implications For example Linux allows creation of files with arbitrary byte sequences in names (including non-minimal UTF-8). If such filename is converted to `String`, which is later used to access the file again, the program will access different file. There is infinite number of ways to compromise security using such tricks. See also [this article](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/MSC10-C.+Character+encoding%3A+UTF8-related+issues) for additional references. I haven't yet found "cheap" solution for filtering out non-nominal sequences in Java

Comment: Lastly, it is worth mentioning, that 5-byte and 6-byte sequences have been banned by newer UTF-8 revisions. They should not be encountered outside of CESU-8, Java modified UTF-8 and similar UTF-8 derivatives, so there is little point in checking for them.

Answer (score 4):

A small solution for real world UTF-8 compatibility checking:

```
public static final boolean isUTF8(final byte[] inputBytes) {
    final String converted = new String(inputBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final byte[] outputBytes = converted.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return Arrays.equals(inputBytes, outputBytes);
}
```

You can check the tests results:

```
@Test
public void testEnconding() {

    byte[] invalidUTF8Bytes1 = new byte[]{(byte)0b10001111, (byte)0b10111111 };
    byte[] invalidUTF8Bytes2 = new byte[]{(byte)0b10101010, (byte)0b00111111 };
    byte[] validUTF8Bytes1 = new byte[]{(byte)0b11001111, (byte)0b10111111 };
    byte[] validUTF8Bytes2 = new byte[]{(byte)0b11101111, (byte)0b10101010, (byte)0b10111111 };

    assertThat(isUTF8(invalidUTF8Bytes1)).isFalse();
    assertThat(isUTF8(invalidUTF8Bytes2)).isFalse();
    assertThat(isUTF8(validUTF8Bytes1)).isTrue();
    assertThat(isUTF8(validUTF8Bytes2)).isTrue();
    assertThat(isUTF8("\u24b6".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))).isTrue();
}
```

Test cases copy from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59428/validating-utf-8-byte-array

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean validUTF8(byte[] input) {
    int i = 0;
    // Check for BOM
    if (input.length >= 3 && (input[0] & 0xFF) == 0xEF
            && (input[1] & 0xFF) == 0xBB & (input[2] & 0xFF) == 0xBF) {
        i = 3;
    }

    int end;
    for (int j = input.length; i < j; ++i) {
        int octet = input[i];
        if ((octet & 0x80) == 0) {
            continue; // ASCII
        }

        // Check for UTF-8 leading byte
        if ((octet & 0xE0) == 0xC0) {
            end = i + 1;
        } else if ((octet & 0xF0) == 0xE0) {
            end = i + 2;
        } else if ((octet & 0xF8) == 0xF0) {
            end = i + 3;
        } else {
            // Java only supports BMP so 3 is max
            return false;
        }

        while (i < end) {
            i++;
            octet = input[i];
            if ((octet & 0xC0) != 0x80) {
                // Not a valid trailing byte
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `CharsetDecoder` might be what you are looking for:

```
@Test
public void testUTF8() throws CharacterCodingException {
    // the desired charset
    final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    // prepare decoder
    final CharsetDecoder decoder = UTF8.newDecoder();
    decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[48];
    new Random().nextBytes(bytes);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    try {
        decoder.decode(buffer);
        fail("Should not be UTF-8");
    } catch (final CharacterCodingException e) {
        // noop, the test should fail here
    }

    final String string = "hallo welt!";
    bytes = string.getBytes(UTF8);
    buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    final String result = decoder.decode(buffer).toString();
    assertEquals(string, result);
}
```

so your function might look like that:

```
public static boolean checkEncoding(final byte[] bytes, final String encoding) {
    final CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName(encoding).newDecoder();
    decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);

    try {
        decoder.decode(buffer);
        return true;
    } catch (final CharacterCodingException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```