# Convert NSData to NSString, but replace invalid UTF-8 with �

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I have some NSData that may or may not contain invalid UTF-8, but any parts of it that are valid UTF-8 should be interpreted as such. If I use `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`, it just returns `nil` if the data has invalid UTF-8 anywhere. How can I get it to replace the invalid UTF-8 with �, like [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder) does?

Comment: You'd probably have to write your own "decoder".

Comment: Its been done before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372870/string-from-nsinputstream-is-not-valid-utf8-how-to-convert-to-utf8-more-lossy